# XMLHttpRequest sending image file

Tags: javascript, php

I want to send a file to the server and process it there, then send a response.
To send a file, I used the method of **FormData()**, everything seems fine, the file is sent, but it is impossible to parse with **$_FILES** + content is only visible through the **php://input**

1. Why is the file is not visible from the **$_FILES**?
2. How to parse?
3. Does **FormData()** Works in all browsers?

My code:

**HTML**

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="file" name="filename">
    <input type="button" name="button" value="Send">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
var form = document.forms.myform;
form.elements.button.onclick = function(){
    var file = form.elements.filename.files[0];
    if(file){
        img(file);
    }else{
        alert("Not file.");
    }
};
function img(file){
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('file', file);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'img.php');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    xhr.send(formdata);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState != 4) return;
        if(xhr.status != 200){
            alert("Status: " + xhr.status);
        }else{
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
print_r($_FILES['file']['size']); // only example, doesn't work

$content = file_get_contents('php://input');
print_r($content); // it's work , result in the photo
?>
```

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdPx7.png)

Comment: Have you tried posting `File` object instead of using `FormData`, using `$_FILES["filename"]["size"]`?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, not working.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously

Comment: And? While not working with jquery. Implemented in the same way my.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Why is the file is not visible from the $_FILES?**

Because it is not necessary to use the encoding.

**2. How to parse?**

With global variable $_FILES

**3. Does FormData() Works in all browsers?**

No. [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData#Browser_compatibility)